# How to solve Elastic Collision?

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-physics

I have been working on an elastic collision demo, and can't seem to get it quite right. The circle1 object seems to collide correctly from one side of the 
 circle2 object, but passes through circle2 if they collide from the opposite side.

How can this elastic collision be modified to be more accurate?

Here is a link to a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ErmOqv) with live demo.

**main.ts**

```
class DemoCanvas {
    canvasWidth: number = 500;
    canvasHeight: number = 500;
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
    constructor() {
        this.canvas.width = this.canvasWidth;
        this.canvas.height = this.canvasHeight;
        this.canvas.style.border = '1px solid black';
        this.canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.canvas.style.left = '50%';
        this.canvas.style.top = '50%';
        this.canvas.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%)';
        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    }

    clear() {
        this.canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    getContext(): CanvasRenderingContext2D {
        return this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

    getWidth(): number {
        return this.canvasWidth;
    }

    getHeight(): number {
        return this.canvasHeight;
    }

    getTop(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }

    getRight(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().right;
    }

    getBottom(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    }    

    getLeft(): number {
        return this.canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    }
}

class Circle {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    dx: number;
    dy: number;
    xVelocity: number;
    yVelocity: number;
    radius: number;
    color: string;
    canvas: DemoCanvas;
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    constructor(x: number, y: number, xVelocity: number, yVelocity: number, color: string, gameCanvas: DemoCanvas) {
        this.radius = 20;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.xVelocity = xVelocity;
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
        this.color = color;
        this.canvas = gameCanvas;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext();
    }

    public draw(): void {
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        this.context.fill();
    }

    public move(): void {
        this.x += this.xVelocity;
        this.y += this.yVelocity;
    }

    checkWallCollision(gameCanvas: DemoCanvas): void {
        let top = 0;
        let right = 500;
        let bottom = 500;
        let left = 0;

        if(this.y < top + this.radius) {
            this.y = top + this.radius;
            this.yVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.x > right - this.radius) {
            this.x = right - this.radius;
            this.xVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.y > bottom - this.radius) {
            this.y = bottom - this.radius;
            this.yVelocity *= -1;
        }

        if(this.x < left + this.radius) {
            this.x = left + this.radius;
            this.xVelocity *= -1;
        }
    }
}

let demoCanvas = new DemoCanvas();
let circle1: Circle = new Circle(250, 250, 5, 5, "#F77", demoCanvas);
let circle2: Circle = new Circle(250, 540, 5, 5, "#7FF", demoCanvas);


function detectCollisions():void {

    if (circle1.x + circle1.radius + circle2.radius > circle2.x 
        && circle1.x < circle2.x + circle1.radius + circle2.radius
        && circle1.y + circle1.radius + circle2.radius > circle2.y 
        && circle1.y < circle2.y + circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
            if (distanceTo() < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
                calculateNewVelocities();
            }
    }
}

function distanceTo():Number {
    var distance = Math.sqrt(((circle1.x - circle2.x) * (circle1.x - circle2.x)) + ((circle1.y - circle2.y) * (circle1.y - circle2.y)));
    if (distance < 0) { 
        distance = distance * -1; 
    }
    return distance;
}

function calculateNewVelocities():void {
    var mass1 = circle1.radius;
    var mass2 = circle2.radius;
    var velX1 = circle1.xVelocity;
    var velX2 = circle2.xVelocity;
    var velY1 = circle1.yVelocity;
    var velY2 = circle2.yVelocity;

    var newVelX1 = (velX1 * (mass1 - mass2) + (2 * mass2 * velX2)) / (mass1 + mass2);
    var newVelY1 = (velY1 * (mass1 - mass2) + (2 * mass2 * velY2)) / (mass1 + mass2);

    circle1.xVelocity = newVelX1;
    circle1.yVelocity = newVelY1;

    circle1.x = circle1.x + newVelX1;
    circle1.y = circle1.y + newVelY1;
}

addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    let mouseX = e.clientX - demoCanvas.getLeft();
    let mouseY = e.clientY - demoCanvas.getTop();
    circle2.x = mouseX;
    circle2.y = mouseY;
});

function loop() {
    demoCanvas.clear();
    circle1.draw();
    circle2.draw();
    circle1.move();
    circle1.checkWallCollision(demoCanvas);
    circle2.checkWallCollision(demoCanvas);
    detectCollisions();
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure where you got your formula to update the velocity of `circle1` when it collides with `circle2`, but [the correct formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional_collision_with_two_moving_objects) is something depending on the relative positions of the two circles (not just the distance between them, but the contact angle as well).

If we assume that `circle2` is going to be stationary (or so massive that `circle1` will not affect its motion), then the code in `calculateNewVelocities()` should look something like this:

```
  var xd = circle1.x - circle2.x; // x displacement between circles
  var yd = circle1.y - circle2.y; // y displacement between circles
  var dsq = xd*xd + yd*yd; // square of distance between circles

  var DV = 2*(velX1*xd + velY1*yd)/dsq; // velocity change factor
  // EDIT
  // fix to prevent orbiting... if circle1 is already rebounding, 
  // leave it alone
  if (DV > 0) {
    DV=0;
  }

  // velocity change is in the opposite direction of 
  // the displacement between circles
  var newVelX1 = velX1 - DV * xd; 
  var newVelY1 = velY1 - DV * yd;
```

<strike>This should give you something vaguely reasonable when the collisions come from the outside.  If you find that the circles overlap, this might result in `circle1` orbiting `circle2` or something crazy like that, so you probably want to tweak that to prevent such things from happening.</strike>

EDIT: I think the "orbiting" issue I mentioned earlier is a consequence of the circles continuing to overlap after the collision, triggering multiple collisions in quick succession.  The fix is to not modify the velocity of `circle1` if it's already heading away from the center of `circle2`.  That way only the first collision has any effect and subsequent detected collisions are ignored until such time as `circle1` is moving toward `circle2` again.

Anyway, that's just a suggestion.  Hope you find what you're looking for.  Good luck.